# Chromium Tabs are reseting flash content in WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I'm working with https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs in my project and I have created my app so the tabs are registered to a WebView. When I'm debugging I noticed that when I was viewing a Youtube video or any flash content and I switched tabs then switch back the content reloaded or the video restarted. Is there any reason this should hapen.

When a tab is selected it is set:  `[self becomeFirstResponder];`
Other than that I have found no other connected way the flash would reset and the rest of the page would remain the same. I'm believing its a setting in WebView whenever it is not visible.

For the comment bellow:

I followed the examples on Github and used MyTabContents.mm to create the contents. Also used a custom webview.

MyTabContents.mm:

```
-(id)initWithBaseTabContents:(CTTabContents*)baseContents {
  if (!(self = [super initWithBaseTabContents:baseContents])) return nil;
    ProgressWebView *wv = [[ProgressWebView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [wv setProgressDelegate:self];

    [[wv mainFrame] loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"]]];
    [wv setShouldUpdateWhileOffscreen:YES];
    webView = wv;
  // Create a NSScrollView to which we add the NSTextView
  NSScrollView *sv = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
  [sv setDocumentView:wv];
  [sv setHasVerticalScroller:NO];

  // Set the NSScrollView as our view
  self.view = sv;

  return self;
}
```

AppDelegate.mm:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CTBrowserWindowController* windowController =
    [[CTBrowserWindowController alloc] initWithBrowser:[MyBrowser browser]];
    [windowController.browser addBlankTabInForeground:YES];
    [windowController showWindow:self];
}
```

MyBrowser.mm:

```
-(CTTabContents*)createBlankTabBasedOn:(CTTabContents*)baseContents {
  // Create a new instance of our tab type
    MyTabContents *contents = [[MyTabContents alloc]
                               initWithBaseTabContents:baseContents];
    [self changeLayout];
  return [contents autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Hi! I'm currently working on a similar project, and I find it tough to insert webView into chrome tab. Would you mind sharing some of your code to achieve that?

Comment: @DmitriyReznik look above